# vivado: Add (included) IP to my design

Tags: instantiation, vivado, vivado-hls

I have instantiation vc707_mb_eth in my design and was hoping to see it in IP sources tab next to sources, hierarchy and compile order. But I don't see IP sources over there. What should I do?

Somethings I tried but failed - 
- Tried adding through IP catalog
- The hierarchy shows a ? left of vc707_mb_eth

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated the Pcore IP in HLS tool then you can simply copy workspace/vc707_mb_eth to workspace/Project/pcores/.

Open the main project in XPS and Rescan User Repositories. This can be found in project tab. Now the newly added Pcore should get populated in the IP catalog under Project local Pcores.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Tools > Settings > IP > Repository

Browse and add your IP repository folder (where you have kept your custom IP folders)

Tested with Vivado 2017.1

Bonus: [Creating custom IP in Vivado (Tested working in VC709 with Microblaze processor)](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/creating-a-custom-ip-block-in-vivado.html)